# Anaconda won't update spyder although there's a new version

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Spyder just notified me that a new version (3.1.4) is available and should be installed. However, Anaconda thinks that version 3.1.3 is the newest version, so I can't update through Anaconda. I tried two ways of updating through Anaconda:

- In Anaconda Navigator, when I click on the gear icon to the top right of the Spyder icon, 'Update application' is grayed out.
- In Anaconda Prompt, I typed `conda update spyder` and got the following output:

  ```
  \# All requested packages already installed.
  \# packages in environment at C:\Python27\Anaconda2:
  \#
  spyder                    3.1.3                    py27_0
  ```

Why does this happen? Anybody dealt with this before? Can I expect Anaconda to recognize the new update in a few days? Will it at least notice when 3.1.5 comes out? Is there a way to update spyder without bypassing Anaconda?

Some extra info:

- According to the Python package index, Spyder 3.1.4 was uploaded on April 24.
- I also tried `conda update conda` which told me I'm already running the latest version of Anaconda: 4.3.16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [release notes](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases):

> Note: This usually takes a couple of days to work until conda packages
>   are created and uploaded by Continuum. Please be patient.